# For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $C$, prove that $C = AB - BA$ can only be found if and only if $C_{11} + C_{22} = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question appears in Hoffman-Kunze Linear Algebra (exercise 1.5, question 8). The book has only introduced linear equations, elementary row operations, row-reduced echolon matrices, and matrix multiplication upto this point so the potential duplicate of this question using trace does not apply to this question.

The first part of the question asks "when it is possible to find $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $C = AB - BA$". I don't really understand the meaning of this query as there are no conditions placed on $C$ so is it okay to assume the answer is always as the product $AB$ and $BA$ always exists if $A$ and $B$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices?

The second part states "prove that $C = AB - BA$ can only be found if and only if $C_{11} + C_{22} = 0$".

For this I did the following:
$$
\text{Let } A = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}; 
  B = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
b_{11} & b_{12} \\ 
b_{21} & b_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}; 
$$

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
AB = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22} \\ 
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21} & a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}; 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
BA = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{21}b_{12} & a_{12}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{12} \\ 
a_{11}b_{21}+a_{21}b_{22} & a_{12}b_{21}+a_{22}b_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}; 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
So 
$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
C &=AB-BA\\ &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_{12}b_{21}-a_{21}b_{12} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22} - (a_{12}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{12}) \\ 
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21}-(a_{11}b_{21}+a_{21}b_{22}) & a_{21}b_{12}-a_{12}b_{21} \\
\end{bmatrix}; 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
From this, it is obvious that $C_{11} = -C_{22} \implies C_{11} + C_{22} = 0$.
But [here (pg. 19)](http://greggrant.org/hoffman_and_kunze.pdf) they go on to further solve $C=AB-BA$ by forming an augmented matrix of $AB-BA$ and coefficients of $C$ and solving that to show that $C_{11} + C_{22} = 0$. Can anyone please explain to me why this step was necessary when one can clearly see in $\eqref{eq3}$ that $C_{11} + C_{22} = 0$? To me it is obvious (or seems to be obvious in any case) that $\eqref{eq3}$ gives the general form of $C$ and all $2 \times 2$ matrices $C$ such that $C=AB - BA$ will be of this form so why then go through the trouble of solving the augmented matrix to show that $C_{11} +C_{22} = 0$? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: This holds not just for $2 \times 2$-matrices, but for square matrices over any size. See [William Kahan, *Only Commutators Have Trace Zero*](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that you were asked to prove that each statement implies the other.  So if you're given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $C$ with diagonal elements that add up to $0$, you're asked to prove that there are some matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $C=AB-BA$

Otherwise, even though you know that every matrix of the form $AB-BA$ has that property (the diagonal elements add to $0$), it's possible that there are some other matrices also having that property that can't be expressed as $AB-BA$.  The second half of the proof rules out that possibility.

Comment: So just to make sure I have understood correctly, what I have done is prove that if $AB-BA$ exists, it satisfies $C$ but not that all matrices $C$ such that $C_{11} + C_{22} = 0$ can be expressed in the form $C=AB-BA$? So my working shows $C=AB-BA \implies C_{11} +C_{22} = 0$ but not $C_{11} +C_{22} = 0 \implies C=AB-BA$ when both implications are necessary for _if and only if_?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  The second half seeks to prove $C_{11}+C_{22}=0 \Rightarrow \exists A, B$ such that $C=AB-BA$.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a proof of the statement:**

**Proof:**

**(⇒) If $C = AB - BA$, then $c_{11} + c_{22} = 0$:**

1. **Taking the trace of both sides:**

   - $tr(C) = tr(AB - BA)$
2. **Applying the property $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$:**

   - $tr(C) = 0$
3. **Expressing the trace of C:**

   - $tr(C) = c_{11} + c_{22} = 0$

**(⇐) If $c_{11} + c_{22} = 0$, then there exist matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $C = AB - BA$:**

`I think the way that you solve is prove this`

**Therefore, we have proven that for a $2x2$ matrix $C$, there exist matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $C = AB - BA$ if and only if $c_{11} + c_{22} = 0$.**

Comment: Uh, maybe don't put everything in bold? It's kinda distracting.